# Python 3.7.2 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named pysqlite2

Tags: python, sqlite, pysqlite

I'm working on windows with python 3.7.2 and using `uszipcode` library and import SearchEngine for getting a list of zip codes which start with the argument of the function.

> I'm getting the following errors:
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\sqlite\pysqlite.py", line 338, in dbapi
>     from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'
> ```
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/tutorial/tutorial/Zillow/zillow_runfile.py", line 38, in <module>
>     st = zl.zipcodes_list(st_items=["100", "770"])    
>   File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\tutorial\tutorial\Zillow\zillow_functions.py", line 32, in zipcodes_list
>     search = SearchEngine()
>   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uszipcode\search.py", line 82, in __init__
>     engine = connect_to_simple_zipcode_db()
>   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uszipcode\db.py", line 49, in connect_to_simple_zipcode_db
>     return engine_creator.create_sqlite(path=simple_db_file_path.abspath)
>   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uszipcode\pkg\sqlalchemy_mate\engine_creator.py", line 51, in create_sqlite
>     return create_engine(_create_sqlite(path), **kwargs)
>   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\__init__.py", line 423, in create_engine
>     return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 87, in create
>     dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
>   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\sqlite\pysqlite.py", line 343, in dbapi
>     raise e
>   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\sqlite\pysqlite.py", line 341, in dbapi
>     from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite  # try 2.5+ stdlib name.
>   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
>     from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
>   File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
>     from _sqlite3 import *
> ImportError: DLL load failed: ‏‏entry module not found.
> ```

I've tried to install different libraries according to recommendations I found online:

1. pip install sqlite-devel
2. pip install sqlite3tools
3. pip install libsqlite3-dev

> for each of the above I got the following error:
>
> ```
>  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement "sqlite-devel <from versions: >
> No matching distribution found for "sqlite-devel"
> ```

```
def zipcodes_list(st_items):
    search = SearchEngine()
    # If st_items is a single zipcode string.
    if isinstance(st_items, str):
        zc_objects = search.by_prefix(st_items)
    # If st_items is a list of zipcode strings.
    elif isinstance(st_items, list):
        zc_objects = [n for i in st_items for n in search.by_prefix(str(i))]
    else:
        raise ValueError("arg 'st_items' must be of type str or list")

    output = [str(i).split(" ", 1)[1].split(">")[0] for i in zc_objects]
    return output
```

Comment: *"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'"*: Try to `pip3 install pysqlite2`

Comment: It's likely something got broken in your Anaconda build. Can you create a new env and test again? Don't install anything through `pip`, use `conda` instead.